# JSF Trouble displaying variable length radio buttons in a custom panelOutput layout

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

New to JavaServer Faces (and Stack Overflow!) so I hope I am describing the issue properly.

In this example I am using PrimeFaces for custom layout.

This is a basic survey application that I am developing.  I am trying to display a variable length set of radio buttons on a page.  The trouble is that when I iterate through the selection items, the FOR attribute doesn't seem to evaluate properly.

This issue occurs when the page iterates through data using ui:repeat.  I have also tried this within dataList and dataTable and had the same effect.

This code works:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{surveyMB.groupHelper}" var="vargroup">
  <primefaces:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <primefaces:panelGrid>

      <ui:repeat value="#{vargroup.questionArray}" var="varquestion">

        <primefaces:selectOneRadio styleClass="selectOneRadio" id="customRadio" value="#{varquestion.selectionId}" layout="custom">
          <f:selectItems value="#{vargroup.selectionMap}" id="selectItems2"></f:selectItems>
        </primefaces:selectOneRadio>

        <primefaces:row>

          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0" />
          </primefaces:column>

          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1" />
          </primefaces:column>

          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2" />                        
          </primefaces:column>

          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt4" for="customRadio" itemIndex="3" />                        
          </primefaces:column>

          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt5" for="customRadio" itemIndex="4" />                    
          </primefaces:column>
        </primefaces:row>

      </ui:repeat>
    </primefaces:panelGrid>
  </primefaces:outputPanel>         
</ui:repeat>
```

This code does not:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{surveyMB.groupHelper}" var="vargroup">
  <primefaces:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <primefaces:panelGrid>

      <ui:repeat value="#{vargroup.questionArray}" var="varquestion">

        <primefaces:selectOneRadio styleClass="selectOneRadio" id="customRadio" value="#{varquestion.selectionId}" layout="custom">
          <f:selectItems value="#{vargroup.selectionMap}" id="selectItems2"></f:selectItems>
        </primefaces:selectOneRadio>

        <primefaces:row>

        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{vargroup.selectionItems}" varStatus="status">
          <primefaces:column>
            <primefaces:radioButton id="opt" for="customRadio" itemIndex="#{status.index}" />
          </primefaces:column>
        </ui:repeat>

        </primefaces:row>

      </ui:repeat>
    </primefaces:panelGrid>
  </primefaces:outputPanel>         
</ui:repeat>
```

When the page iterates through the two ui:repeat tags, the customRadio id is updated for each question.  In the first example, the FOR attributes of the static radio buttons update properly and reference the unique customRadio id.  In the second example, the FOR attribute does not appear to evaluate properly and throws the following exception:

Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression "customRadio" referenced from "form1:j_id373995743_164ab843:2:j_id373995743_164ab90b:0:j_id373995743_164aba20:0:opt"

As each question can have a variable length of responses and different answers, I'd like to be able to display them dynamically and not have to hard code static responses for each possibility.  Is there a work around to get this to display properly, or perhaps a process that anyone can suggest to do this differently?

(Note: There may be other issues with the way I built the radioButton within the repeat but the primary error is the one I am most concerned about)

**UPDATE:** My goal is to do span my responses across multiple columns with the response options across the header row (eventually horizontally and vertically).  [See this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077687/enterprise-java/group-radio-buttons-inside-a-jsf-datatable-component.html).  And without (hopefully) having to build a custom ui component.  I know that may be dreaming!

But the main goal is for the radio button lengths to be variable.  One set of answers may have five responses, another may only have three.  But each set has the same number so I am not confusing the tables.

Without some way to override or force a prepend action on the nested for attribute, the only way I can think is to hack the helper classes I have in the backing bean to display each radio button item as a unique field so I don't have to iterate through the options.

Comment: You may want to pick up one of the layouts of [`<p:selectOneRadio>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) instead. It sounds better to me (the layout can also be customized).  Currently, you are referring to a `<p:radioButton>` (`for`) from within a `<ui:repeat>` loop which is located in another `<ui:repeat>` loop which will then be unreachable just by referring to it using its simple id, `customRadio`. The ids of those dynamically generated `<p:radioButton>`s will have automatically be prepended with the repeating index. Try looking into the generated HTML code.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue and the rabbit hole that I've been down for several days now.  The example IS the custom layout for <p:selectOneRadio>.  The only other options are pageDirection and lineDirection for default layout.  My goal has been to develop a grid of questions with the option labels in the header and buttons across each successive row, and the working example nailed it without resorting to a custom UI component.  In that example, all of the id's are prepended, and all of the for's are prepended to match.  But not when there is one more level of nesting like the second example.